# My class/id/highlight tags are not working

Tags: html, css, class, styles

I'm new to coding. So basically i'm doing an online web developers course before entering a bootcamp and i'm using Sublime Text for my code, i'm super stuck!

So in this exercise the styling is done in the html.
The problems are with: 
**John
body {[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niSTT.png)
    color: red;**
The styling does not show!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Specificity</title>
    <style type="text/css">
            body {
            color: red;
        }

        ul {
            color: blue;
        }

        li {
            color: orange;
            .highlight {
                color: yellow;
            }
            #special {
                colour: pink;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hello!!!</p>
    <ul>
        <li id="special" class="highlight">John</li>
        <li>Paul</li>
        <li class="highlight">George</li>
        <li>Ringo</li>
    </ul>
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: maybe you know or see the problem with my code why the highlight, class and ID tags are not working?

Comment: In order to assist, it's probably best to include not just the source of the page, but also a (cropped) image of what it looks like for you and what you expect it to look like as a result.

Comment: Your style rule for `li` is broken; it's missing the closing `}` (this isn't the only problem, but it's going to block fixing everything else).

Comment: Wow! Thank you OdatNurd!!!! It fixed that problem. It looks like the example. Great thanks! Any tips for a starter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your style for id #special colour is not a css property, change this to color. Also you are missing a } after your li properties.

Try this

```
<style type="text/css">
     body {
        color: red;
     }

     ul { 
     color: blue;
     }

     li {
        color: orange;
     }

     .highlight {
        color: yellow;
     }

     #special {
        color: pink;
     }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `color` that refers to text color.
The code you presented overrides the elements you set, there is a big confusion, that causes the code not to work.

Also missing `}` in `li` tag

```
        body {
            color: red;
        }
        ul { 
          color: blue;
         }
         li {
            color: orange;
         }
        .highlight {
            color: yellow;
         }
         #special {
            color: pink; /* no such thing colour in css */
         }
```

Also why did you applied specail ID and highlight class in the same `li` tag, that caused one of the elements to be override the other.

```
    <li id="special">John</li>
    <li>Paul</li>
    <li class="highlight">George</li>
    <li>Ringo</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're writing your css as if you were using sass. Vanilla css does not support nesting. In order to target an `li` with `.highlight` you should say `li.highlight {...}`. Or in this case you could just use `.highlight`.
For your special class you have spelled color as colour.
Here is your fixed code:

```css
body {
 color: red;
}
ul { 
color: blue;
}
li {
 color: orange;
}
li.highlight {
 color: yellow;
}
#special {
 color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Specificity</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Hello!!!</p>
  <ul>
   <li id="special" class="highlight">John</li>
   <li>Paul</li>
   <li class="highlight">George</li>
   <li>Ringo</li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

You also seem to have an additional closing style tag at the end of your html or some reason.